# Send several files to printer when clicking a link in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to print several files (pdf and ppt documents) automatically when a user clicks a link, for example. This files have to be programatically chosen taking values from a form within the page.
They're not going to be many files, only up to 5, maybe less, each time the user clicks to print them. For example:
`http://server/folder1/folderA/file1.pdf`
`http://server/folder2/folderB/file2.ppt`
`http://server/folder3/folderC/file3.pdf`
`http://server/folder4/folderD/file4.ppt`
I prefer it to only prompts the user one time to print documents although I don't know if this'll require to merge all them together in a single one. I really don't know how to achieve this: i'm open to Javascript, jQuery, ASP... Any idea? Is this feasible? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Especially not if the files aren't HTML (for HTML files you could call `window.print();` to open the "Print" dialog).

ASP would only run on the server so that's not a solution. It might be possible with a Java applet but I think you should rather provide links to the files and explain the user how to print them.